# How to count complete observations for specific variables in a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with several hundred variables that contains missing values that are denoted by NA. There are 571 observations in total. I'm only interested in 20 of the variables in this `data.frame`. In other words, I want to define a complete observation as an any observation that has data in all 20 variables of interest.

One way of getting around this is by running a linear regression, which will delete any observations that have missing values. I.e. it will state something like:

`(196 observations deleted due to missingness)`

This will allow me to infer that my sample size is equal to 571 minus 196. But there must be a better way to do it. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply remove any observations that contain NA in any variable, use [`na.omit()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/na.fail.html). If you want to select only some of the variables, subset them first with [`subset()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/subset.html).

Example:

```r
# some data
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1,2,3,4,5,NA),
  b = c(NA,2,3,4,5,6),
  c = c(NA,NA,3,4,5,6)
)

# omit rows with NAs
na.omit(df)
#>   a b c
#> 3 3 3 3
#> 4 4 4 4
#> 5 5 5 5

# use only "a" and "b" variables
na.omit(subset(df, select = c("a", "b")))
#>   a b
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3
#> 4 4 4
#> 5 5 5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can count the number of observations with [`nrow()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/nrow.html):

```
nrow(na.omit(df))
#> [1] 3
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! For anyone else, my final code reads ```nrow(na.omit(subset(finaldata, select = c("child_age96", "log3Tblood"))))```

Comment: @goose144 Great, I'm glad it works! And thanks so much for your feedback for other people!

Answer (score 1):

Use `complete.cases`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1,NA,2,NA,3),
  b = c(NA,5,3,5,6),
  c = c(NA,NA,3,5,NA)
)

df[complete.cases(df),]
nrow(df[complete.cases(df),])
```

**Output**

```
 a b c
3 2 3 3

1
```